# Laravel 5 on EC2 returns the wrong IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I'm working on a EC2 in a VPC using Laravel 5. When using `GeoIP::getLocation($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])` I get 73.251.135.152 as my ip address, however when I ask Google I get an IPv6 of 2601:5cb:c200:bf18:10ce:8647:1198:8e7d which is totally messing up my MaxMind Geo cities as 73.251.135.152 is an unknown location.

As far as I can tell it's only on the EC2 and I can not reproduce this anywhere else. Anyone have a solution for this?

```
(
    [ip] => 73.251.135.152
    [isoCode] => US
    [country] => United States
    [city] => 
    [state] => 
    [postal_code] => 
    [lat] => 38
    [lon] => -97
    [timezone] => 
    [continent] => NA
    [default] => 
)
```

Comment: do you have an ELB (Elastic load balancer) infront of the VPC?  or does the request land up directly @ your VPC machine?

Comment: It goes direct to the EC2